# Homogeneous Matrices (elements size)

Tags: matrices

I would like to homogenize the size of the elements of the two matrices, but it is impossible for now because there are these fractions. It is really ugly like this.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,latexsym} 
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{R_a}{L_a} & -\frac{K_g}{L_a} \\
\frac{Ka}{J} & - \frac{f}{J}  
 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
 i_a(t)  \\
 \omega(t)
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I use TABstacks to build the elements.  I control the vertical baselineskip (22pt) and the the horizontal inter-column gap (8pt).

I also created my own `\vphantom` strut to extend the range of the vector elements.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,latexsym,tabstackengine} 
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\setstackgap{L}{22pt}
\setstacktabbedgap{8pt}
\def\mystrut{\vphantom{\frac{K_g}{J}}}
\parenMatrixstack{
-\frac{R_a}{L_a} & -\frac{K_g}{L_a} \\
\frac{Ka}{J} & - \frac{f}{J}  
}
\parenVectorstack{
 i_a(t)\mystrut  \\
 \omega(t)\mystrut
}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to present the result in `\displaystyle`.  Since `amsmath` is loaded, one can use `\dfrac` to achieve the result.  The "**L**ong" stackgap has been increased to 34pt.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,latexsym,tabstackengine} 
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\setstackgap{L}{34pt}
\setstacktabbedgap{8pt}
\def\mystrut{\vphantom{\dfrac{K_g}{J}}}
\parenMatrixstack{
-\dfrac{R_a}{L_a} & -\dfrac{K_g}{L_a} \\
\dfrac{Ka}{J} & - \dfrac{f}{J}  
}
\parenVectorstack{
 i_a(t)\mystrut  \\
 \omega(t)\mystrut
}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do I need to create a .sty file?

Comment: @EduardoCasseres You can download it directly, along with the documentation, at http://ctan.org/pkg/tabstackengine.  You will also need the associated `stackengine` package at http://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine.

Comment: Is there any way to reduce the size of the vector's elements?

Comment: @EduardoCasseres The vector elements are the normal size.  It is the matrix elements that have been reduced.  The matrix elements can be increased in size by using `\displaystyle\frac` (or `\dfrac` if using `amsmath`).  I will revise my answer to demonstrate.